# How to I automate copying 1 Agent job from Instance A to Instance B?

Tags: sql-server

I have a Always On cluster of 2012 through to 2019 instances. Don't want to over complicate using it for my Customers. I would like to be in a position of the customer creating 1 job through the listener on the primary. Then have a Automated process to copy them across to the secondary and DR. Without my intervention or their creating on each instance.

What is the best way of Automate ether in SQL or Powershell (or anything else i haven't thought of). Coping 1 Agent job from Instance 1 too Instance 2 without DBA or Customer intervention?

Comment: Check out [Copy-DbaAgentJob](https://docs.dbatools.io/#Copy-DbaAgentJob) on the [dbatools site](https://dbatools.io/)

Comment: @ScottHodgin wow! if that works this will be easier than i thought! Cheers man!